# Can not implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApp2.tbl_user' to 'WindowsFormsApp2.BLL.User'

Tags: c#, winforms, dto

I am trying to create a logIn Form using c# and LINQ to SQL. When I try to verify the entred login with the database data :

```
private void LogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User u = d.tbl_user.Where(c => c.username == username.Text && c.pwd == password.Text  ).Single();
}
```

it returns me this Error :

> Can not implicitly convert type 'WindowsFormsApp2.tbl_user' to 'WindowsFormsApp2.BLL.User'

Edit : Also I tried to Add data to database but it returns the same Error :

```
private void ajouter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArticleBLL a = new ArticleBLL()
    {
        Designiation = des.Text,
        Quantite_stock = Convert.ToInt32(quantite.Text),
        Magasin = dbContext.tbl_magazin.Where(c => c.libelle == magazin.Text).Select(c => c.id).Single(),
        Nature = nature.Text,
        Categorie = dbContext.tbl_categorie.Where(c => c.libelle == categorie.Text).Select(c => c.id).Single(),
        Date_arrive = DateTime.Parse(date.Text),
        Ajoute_par = 1
    };

    dbContext.tbl_article.InsertOnSubmit(a);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

It gives me a red line under :  `dbContext.tbl_article.InsertOnSubmit(a);` saying that :

> Impossible to convert type dbContext.tbl_article.InsertOnSubmit(a);

Heeelp !! I dont know where is the problem .

*** Here my ArticleBll.cs :**

```
class ArticleBLL
{
    public int Code_article { get; set; }
    public string Designiation { get; set; }
    public int Quantite_stock { get; set; }

    public int Magasin { get; set; }

    public string Nature { get; set; }
    public decimal Prix { get; set; }

    public int Categorie { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_arrive { get; set; }
    public int Ajoute_par { get; set; }
}
```

***Here is my tbl_article : ***
[my table article image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1wWa.png)

Comment: `User u` should be `tbl_user u`

Comment: I dont get it ..can you please Sir explain why i should put the resut in the table ?

Comment: As @ChetanRanpariya commented, in your `LogIn_Click` instead of `User u = ...` you must use `tbl_user u = ...` because you filter `d.tbl_user` by some criteria and the result is a single item of `tbl_user`. If you need it to be an instance of `User` class, then create a `User` and assign to its properties whatever property you need from `tbl_user u`.

Comment: The same thing is when you try to insert. Your `dbContext.tbl_article.InsertOnSubmit(a);` can only insert `tbl_article` instances, you have to create a new `tbl_article` like `var tblArticle = new tbl_article();` and assign `a`-'s properties to `tblArticle`-'s properties. And then you should have `dbContext.tbl_article.InsertOnSubmit(tblArticle);`

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much now i understand Thank you Sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi I think you should try below code:

```
var u = d.tbl_user.FirstOrDefault(c => c.username == username.Text && c.pwd == password.Text);
```

And compare why it's not matching with your `User` class after you can typecast u with user.

Comment: it works with var. But I can't sse why it doesn't work with class User ... Thank you for ur help ! I appreciate it !

Comment: I had the same error again while trying to add data to my database .. can you please help me ?

Comment: @jasmin you can use predicates in `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @milmike can you let me know your code so I think I can try

Comment: Hi @Ghukas can you please explain how predicates are useful in FirstOrDefault() thanks in advance